# pyinstaller3.4 python3.5 --key=key-string caused problems

Tags: pyinstaller

All,

I am trying to compile and encrypt the "hello_world.py" with pyinstaller's --key=key-string and it keeps causing issue when I am trying to open the .exe file. The warning says "Failed to execute script pyiboot01_bootstrap". The problem was gone when I took the --key=key-string out but that left the deployed executable not encrypted. Is this some sort of python 3.5 pyinstaller 3.4 compatibility issues? Any insights on this would be much appreciated.

Environment:
python 3.6
pyinstaller 3.4
pycryptodome 3.6.6 
Windows 10

Answer (score 0):

The pycryptodome module is not compatible with PyInstaller encryption.

See: [pyinstaller: problem when using --key command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56911760/pyinstaller-problem-when-using-key-command)