# pyinstaller: problem when using --key command

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I'm trying to use ***pyinstaller -F --key="123456" my.py*** to encrypt exe, but got this error instead:
[image]

And here is the content of my.py, no extra files or datas needed:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def get_page_source(page_num):
    print('Crawling page %d' % page_num)

    url = 'http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-%d.html' % page_num
    r = requests.get(url)
    return r.text


def get_book_info(page_source):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page_source, features='lxml')
    titles = soup.select('h3 > a')
    for title in titles:
        print(title.get('title'))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # 1-50
    for i in range(1, 51):
        page_source = get_page_source(i)
        get_book_info(page_source)
```

Don't have any clue on how to solve it. It works fine when I stop using --key command.

PyInstaller==3.4 Python==3.6

Comment: It is a known bug for using [pycryptodome](https://pypi.org/project/pycryptodome/). I think you should install the old [pycrypto](https://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/) for this to work.

Comment: Thanks! I think you can post it as an answer, would help some people. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is known bug and it is because Pyinstaller encryption is not compatible with [pycryptodome](https://pypi.org/project/pycryptodome/). So you need to install the old [PyCrypto](https://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/) to make it work.

There is a good answer in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41843266/microsoft-windows-python-3-6-pycrypto-installation-error?answertab=votes#tab-top) for installing the old `PyCrypto`.

```
pip install pycrypto
```

Answer (score 1):

install: `pip install cryptography` to solve the problem & for the lates encryption ver of pycrypto. PyCrypto 2.x is unmaintained, obsolete, and contains security vulnerabilities.
[know more at PyCrypto](https://www.pycrypto.org/)